# Error creating azurerm_monitor_metric_alert for IPsec Site-to-Site on Azure with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-monitoring

So I am trying to create monitoring alerts for IPsec VPN Connections on a Azure Virtual Network Gateway. We have automated the creation of the actual deployment of the connections. However when I try to deploy the monitoring portion of the bundle I'm getting an error. The plan looks good but fails when actually deploying the Alerts.

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_action_rule_action_group" "vpn-alerts" {
  name                = "vpn-alerts"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-canadacentral-prod-region.name
  action_group_id     = azurerm_monitor_action_group.azure-vpn-monitor.id

  scope {
    type         = "ResourceGroup"
    resource_ids = [azurerm_resource_group.rg-canadacentral-prod-region.id]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "main" {
  name                = "vgw-${var.azure_region}-${var.vdc_env}-monitor"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-canadacentral-prod-region.name
  short_name          = "ipsec-alerts"

#   webhook_receiver {
#     name        = "callmyapi"
#     service_uri = "http://example.com/alert"
#   }
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "ipsec_tunnel" {
  for_each = {for cn in var.vpn:  cn.name => cn}
  name                = "lgw-${var.azure_region}-${var.vdc_env}-region-${each.value.name}-connectivity"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-canadacentral-prod-region.name
  scopes              = [azurerm_local_network_gateway.region_to_site[each.value.name].id]
  description         = "IPSec tunnel did not receive any traffic for over 5 minutes"

  criteria {
    metric_namespace = "Microsoft.Insights/metricAlerts"
    metric_name      = "BitsInPerSecond"
    aggregation      = "Average"
    operator         = "LessThanOrEqual"
    threshold        = 0

    dimension {
      name     = "ApiName"
      operator = "Include"
      values   = ["*"]
    }
  }

  action {
    action_group_id = azurerm_monitor_action_group.main.id
  }
}
```

[Inital Failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LFIx.png)

So I tried changing the metric namespace to both

```
Microsoft.Network/connections
```

```
Microsoft.Network/localNetworkGateways
```

[And recieved this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrm4Q.png)

This is code used to deploy the alerting, Could it be an issue with the actual alert namespace not being found? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your question! [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. Please edit your question to turn the image into well-formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment , for vpn gateways:***

Received similar error:

```
creating or updating Monitor Metric Alert: (Name "example-metricalert" / Resource Group "xxx "): insights.MetricAlertsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="ResourceNotFound" Message="{\"code\":\"BadRequest\",\"message\":\"Detect invalid value: Microsoft.Insights/metricAlerts for query parameter: 'metricnamespace', the value must be: Microsoft.Network/vpnGateways if the query parameter is provided, you can also skip this optional query parameter
```

[image]

---

***Code:***

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-network"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_wan" "example" {
  name                = "example-vwan"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_hub" "example" {
  name                = "example-hub"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  virtual_wan_id      = azurerm_virtual_wan.example.id
  address_prefix      = "10.0.1.0/24"
}

resource "azurerm_vpn_gateway" "example" {
  name                = "example-vpng"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_hub_id      = azurerm_virtual_hub.example.id
}




resource "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "ag" {
  name                = "myactiongroup"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  short_name          = "ipsec-alerts"

}
resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "alert" {
  name                = "example-metricalert"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  scopes              = ["/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/vpnGateways"]
  description         = "IPSec tunnel did not receive any traffic for over 5 minutes"
  target_resource_type = "Microsofts.Network/vpnGateways"
  
  #Microsoft.Network/vpnGateways
  criteria { 
    metric_namespace = "Microsoft.Insights/metricAlerts"
    metric_name      = "Percentage CPU"
    aggregation      = "Total"
    operator         = "GreaterThan"
    threshold        = 80
  }

  action {
    action_group_id = azurerm_monitor_action_group.ag.id
  }
}
```

[image]

---

So here metric namespace is correct but it doesnot contain metrics `CPU percentage` and all.

I checked the issue is due to non support of the tried namespaces for the newtwork related metrics:

Only below are supported for the metrics as they require

***[metrics-supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported#microsoftnetworkprivatednszones)***

- Try with namespace `Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateways`  as localNetworkGateways is not the supported one.
- And if you check Virtual network gateway , Local network gateway is involved in VPN connections .see [Configure IPsec/IKE policy for site-to-site VPN connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/user/azure-stack-vpn-s2s?view=azs-2206&tabs=az1%2Caz2%2Caz3%2Caz4%2Caz5%2Caz8%2Caz6%2Caz7)

**In my case, as i am setting  monitor alerts for VPN gateway,
i used "Microsoft.Network/vpnGateways" in metric_namespace and "AverageBandwidth" as metric , which only supports average as aggregation and it executed succssully.**

According to below table from above ***[metrics-supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported#microsoftnetworkprivatednszones)*** :

[image]

similarly check for vnetgateway:

[image]

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "alert" {
  name                = "example-metricalert"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  scopes              = ["/subscriptions/xx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/vpnGateways/kavexample-vpng"]
  description         = "IPSec tunnel did not receive any traffic for over 5 minutes"
 // target_resource_type = "Microsofts.Network/vpnGateways"
  
  #Microsoft.Network/vpnGateways
  criteria { 
    metric_namespace="Microsoft.Network/vpnGateways"
    metric_name      = "AverageBandwidth"
    aggregation      = "Average"
    operator         = "GreaterThan"
    threshold        = 80
  }

  action {
    action_group_id = azurerm_monitor_action_group.ag.id
  }
}
```

[image]

---

***we can then monitor in insights:***

[image]